# (Dynamic FE analysis) Proportionality between time step and displacement

Tags: finite-element

I am currently adopting a Newmark algorithm, for which the system of equation is

$$(M+{\beta}{\Delta}t^2{K}){d_i}=\beta{\Delta}t^2{F_i}+Md_{i-1}+{\Delta}tM\dot{d}_{i-1}+{\Delta}t^2M\left(\frac{1}{2}-\beta\right)\ddot{d}_{i-1}$$

Say I solve the problem for a given time step ${\Delta}t$ and find $d_{i}$. If I want to find ${\alpha}d_{i}$ where $\alpha$ is known, by which amount must the time step be multiplied?

Comment: Have you checked the stability criteria in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newmark-beta_method).

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you know how to find $d_i$, to get $\alpha d_i$ you just multiply the vector by the number $\alpha$. I must be completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes, if I multiply the whole right-hand side vector by $\alpha$ I will get ${\alpha}{d_{i}}$. But I don't want to do that. Rather, I would like to multiply only ${\Delta}t$ by a given constant number in order to get ${\alpha}{d_{i}}$. My question is, what number is that?

Comment: You can't do that. You have $d_i = (M+\beta \Delta t^2 K)^{-1} f$ with $f$ the right hand side of the equation. There is not going to be a factor by which to multiple $\Delta t$ so that you get $\alpha$ times the solution $d_i$. But more importantly I just don't understand why you want to do that either. Tell us *what* you want to do, rather than how you want to do.

Comment: I would like to model fracture of concrete structures in dynamics. The finite elements are linear elastic until reach its strength. So, I would like to search the time increment for which only a single finite element fails.

Comment: I don't see what you want to do. Run your equations at 0.99 of the maximum stable time-step and then record when the first element fails and then take appropriate action.

Comment: NNN, the problem is that, eventually, more than one element will fail for a given time step.